# Calling a function from a class without object

Tags: python, function, class

I have a question.
this is my code:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, vnaam, anaam, nummer, geboorte, mail, cijfer):
        self.vnaam = vnaam
        self.anaam = anaam
        self.mail = mail
        self.nummer = nummer
        self.geboorte = geboorte
        self.cijfer = cijfer
        self.cijfers = []

    def mailadres(self):
        mailadres = self.nummer + "@rocfriesepoort.nl"
        mailadres = mailadres.replace(' ', "")
        mailadres = mailadres.lower()
        return mailadres

    def cijfervullen(self):
        self.cijfers.append(self.cijfer)

    def gemiddelde(self):
        gemid = (sum(self.cijfers) / len(self.cijfers))
        return gemid

student1 = student("Peter", "Veelsma", "123456", "23/4/2003", "", 8)
student2 = student("Anna", "Grijpstra", "325764", "11/9/2004", "", 7)
student3 = student("Bart", "van Tongeren", "876352", "9/11/2001", "", 5)

studenten = [student1, student2, student3]

for x in studenten:
    x.mail = (x.mailadres())
    x.cijfervullen()
    print(x.vnaam, x.anaam, "-", x.nummer, "-", x.mail, "-", x.geboorte, "-", "Cijfer:", *x.cijfers)
```

i want to use the funtion gemiddelde() wihout calling a object.
i just want to print the output of that funtion. I already tried something with @staticmethod, but that doesnt work

how do i do this?

Comment: `gemiddelde()` uses `self`, so it is not possible to call the function without an instance of the class the function belongs to.

Comment: You can use `@classmethod` but only if the function doesn't refer to `self`, because `self` means you need an object instance.

Comment: In `gemiddelde()` method you are referring to `cijfers` attribute of  `self` which is an *instance* of your class, so at the end you will need to use an instance for see the results of this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gemiddelde` is an *instance method*. To call it, you need an instance:

```
print(student1.gemiddelde())
```

Instance methods are the most common type of methods in Python classes. These are so called because they can access unique data of their instance.

Here, `gemiddelde` needs access to the `cijfers` attribute.

Take a look at the documentation about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/tutorial/classes.html).